# not able to get a separated string from statement array<String^>^ dataOfAllCells = strOfAllItems->Split(',');

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++

'getting the whole string in strOfAllItems[0];
i want separate the string and store it in each array index of strOfAllItems.

language : visual c++'

```
String^ strOfAllItems;

    strOfAllItems = DGVtoString(dgSale, ',');
    if (strOfAllItems->IsNullOrEmpty(strOfAllItems))
    {
        MessageBox::Show("DGVtoString did not worked.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
        return;
    }
    
    array<String^>^ dataOfAllCells = strOfAllItems->Split(',');



function DGVtoString :

public: String^ DGVtoString(DataGridView^ dgv, char delimiter)
{
    StringBuilder^ sb = gcnew StringBuilder();
    for each(DataGridViewRow^ row in dgv->Rows)
    {
        for each(DataGridViewCell^ cell in row->Cells)
                {
            sb->Append(cell->Value);
            sb->Append(',');
        }
        sb->AppendLine();
    }
    sb->Remove(sb->Length - 1, 1); // Removes the last delimiter 
    return sb->ToString();
}
```